# Entanglement - Natural and Unavoidable or Difficult to Do and Flimsy?

Tags: entanglement

I’m hoping the quantum community here might weigh in with some thoughts on something that is bothering me regarding quantum entanglement…something that seems as big a disagreement in the quantum world as the Copenhagen theory, and it’s possibly directly related.

I’m of the belief that quantum entanglement is natural and unavoidable, and that any two quantum particles that “touch” or come near each other will not only entangle, but entangled the rest of their lives. I know at least a few very well-respected quantum theorists and scientists hold this view.

The opposite, seemingly far more popular side of the argument, believes that entanglement is fairly difficult to do and the entanglement bond is flimsy and easy to break. The former side believes that decoherence is simply the measurement devices getting entangled with the quantum entangled particles we are trying to follow and our inability to track/separate the additional entanglement impacts on the original tracked particles (i.e. like trying to follow a drop of colored dye dropped into an ocean).

Which side do you fall on, is entanglement easy and hard to avoid or hard to do and easily broken? 
Any additional thoughts you could add would be much appreciated.

I'm thinking about writing an article on this subject and share some of the replies, so if you reply, consider that I may print it in my article.

Comment: The way you're presenting your question is basically as an opinion poll, and says things which are not obvious about conventional understanding among physicists (which would in any case be irrelevant to a technical question). Could you perhaps rework your post to be more focused on a specific answerable question?

Comment: Well, I'm doing my best. I don't want an opinion poll so much as I want to hear what other more knowledgeable people think, either pro or con. Ideas and math matter most to me, not whether I have a higher number of people who believe one way or another. I already apparently believe a less popular theory, so popularity isn't one of my primary concerns. It's ideas and knowledge. I'm trying to gain some. If you know of a better way to ask the question to get what I'm going after, please share, if you don't mind.

Comment: How about this that seems to be the base of my question: When two quantum particles collide, do they naturally and unavoidably entangle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no contradiction. Entanglement indeed is a natural property; it is difficult to keep pure states for a long time, because they tend to interact and get entangled with environment; but it also difficult to obtain a particular entangled state, such as Bell state.

Uncontrolled entanglement is natural, controlled entanglement requires high technology, and is important for quantum computation.

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree with kludg's answer. To follow it up:

> entanglement is natural and unavoidable
>
> the entanglement bond is flimsy and easy to break

These two things are intrinsically linked. Entanglement has a property called *monogamy*. If particle $A$ is entangled to both particles $B$ and $C$, the more it is entangled with $B$, the less it is entangled with $C$. So, another particle comes along and naturally interacts, acquiring a bit of entanglement (natural & unavoidable), the existing entanglement bonds are lessened (i.e. it was flimsy and easy to break).

There is a philosophical question that appears regarding the "breaking" of entanglement. As I've just described it, entanglement isn't broken as such, just shifted around, whereas there's this magical process of measurement that does break entanglement. Some would claim that measurement is basically just a unitary process and there isn't actually a collapse, it's just another entangling process (this is, crudely, the many-worlds interpretation). So, according to them, there would be no breaking of entanglement.